# Y Ticks in Wrong Order

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset that I'm plotting using plotly with python and for some reason the y-axis ticks are in the wrong order. When the value on the y-axis decreases the line on the chart is going higher.

Here is a small example of how the dataset is structured:

```
dfmeds = 

Start       Name                Medication  End           Dose
2020-12-09  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-10  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-11  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-12  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-13  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-14  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    5
2020-12-15  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    4
2020-12-16  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    4
2020-12-17  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    4
2020-12-18  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    4
2020-12-19  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    4
2020-12-20  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    3
2020-12-21  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    3
2020-12-22  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    3
2020-12-23  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    3
2020-12-24  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    3
2020-12-25  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    2
2020-12-26  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    2
2020-12-27  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    2
2020-12-28  Yosemite Sam        Lexapro     2021-06-30    2
```

and the code I'm using to create the graph...

```
    fig2 = px.line(dfmeds, x='Start', y="Dose", color = "Medication",
        # labels={"Episode_Count": tally + " per Shift",
        #         "Target":"Target",
        #         "Yr_Mnth": "Date" },
        title="Medication Dosages")
    fig2.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,)
    fig2.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear')
    fig2.update_layout(template = 'plotly_white',hovermode="x unified")
```

and frustratingly this is my output:

[image]

Note the green trace in particular. Have any of you kind souls out there in the annals of the web came across this strange phenomenon?! I've looked at the docs for y-ticks and can't find any method of controlling the order...

############################# EDIT ##################################

As two people have pointed out in the comments the reason the for the lack of numerical order was that the "Dose" column was being passed in as an object and was therefore being handled as a categorical.

So I changed the dtype to numerical to address:

```
    dfmeds["Dose"] = pd.to_numeric(dfmeds["Dose"])
```

Though that introduced a new problem, due to the substantial range of dosage values the y-axis ticks is all bunched up:

[image]

I feel I should be able to fix that by formatting the y-ticks though the best case scenario would be to keep the categorical input and control the order as means the value of each trace can clearly be seen on the y-axis.

If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any possibility your `Dose` column are strings (i.e. `object` in `df.info()`)? If that's the case, there's no relationship between them ('300' is as far from '1' as it is from '299')

Comment: What is the type of `dfmeds['Dose']`?

Comment: You guys were both right, it was being passed in as an object! Though when I converted to numeric it introduced a new issue... I've added an edit above if you're interested in taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments part of the issue was that the y-axis values were being passed in as an object and therefore were treated categorically.

Easily addressed by converting dfmeds['Dose'] to numeric, in my case I also had to extract text from some cells also which is handled in the first line:

```
#strip non numeric characters
dfmeds['Dose'] = dfmeds['Dose'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
#convert to numeric
dfmeds['Dose'] = pd.to_numeric(dfmeds['Dose'])
```

The issue referred to in the "edit" was that I had "tickmode" set to linear. Which was also easily addressed by removing:

```
fig2.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear')
```

I hope this helps some other poor soul in need out there, happy programming!